# How to make apache, node.js, beego and https work nicely together?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a server who I want to serve up two different sites:

- a.example.com should be directed to node.js listening on 8081/8443
- b.example.com should be directed to beego listening on 8081/8444

I have apache httpd listening on 80 and using the following directives to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName a.example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName b.example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Using these over http works like you'd imagine. Now my problem is with securing the sites with https. When I have either of the sites listening on port 80 with Apache httpd turned off, https is functional. However getting them to play nice with Apache hasn't been easy.

So I tried adding

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName a.example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/a/sslcert/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/a/sslcert/server.key

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

and equivalent for b.example.com however trying to access https://{a|b}.example.com gives

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

I figure this has to do with both beego and node.js are using their own httpd to establish https, so again I try ... but without the 4 SSL-related lines.
The result this time is

```
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (chrome)
Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long (firefox)
```

I have no idea what to try next, google turns up empty so I hope there is some help to get from you guys/girls?

I need both beego and node.js sites to be able to set their own https settings, so they can work both with and without Apache in front. Is this doable?

```
# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server a.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-   vhosts.conf:30)
     port 443 namevhost a.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
     port 443 namevhost b.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:62)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)
     port 80 namevhost www.pontusfa.lk (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)
             alias example.com
     port 80 namevhost a.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:48)
     port 80 namevhost b.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:80)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/srv/http"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="http" id=33
Group: name="http" id=33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point on connecting to the node/beego with HTTPS.

Just try:

Customers ---> HTTPS-Apache ---> HTTP-node

Take in mind node is singlethreaded, so you should not use it on intensive CPU (and SSL it is) otherwise request will be queued.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why I didn't think of doing it like that. Yes this is my first time trying to setup apache/a reverse proxy.